# Combine columns in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Having a data frame like:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [9, 8, 7], 'c': [4, 5, 6]})
df
```

[image]

I would like to have a data frame with:

- A factor/category column `['a', 'b']`. The name of this column, I do not care.
- A column which has the old value of the `a` or `b` column, depending on the `['a', 'b']` factor. The name of this column, I do not care.
- Keep `c` column values and name (the actual data frame has several columns that I would like to keep).
- I do not care about the order of the columns in the resulting data frame, nor if some (or any) of them are set as index.

This is an example of what I would like to get:

```
df['name_a'] = 'a'
df['name_b'] = 'b'

c0 = pandas.concat([df['name_a'], df['name_b']])
c1 = pandas.concat([df['a'], df['b']])
c2 = pandas.concat([df['c'], df['c']])

newdf = pandas.concat([c0, c1, c2], axis=1)
newdf
```

[image]

Is there a better way to achieve the same result? I feel it is very ugly that way. Perhaps a `pandas` function that I am missing and makes the code much cleaner and simple to understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html):

```
print (pd.melt(df,id_vars='c', var_name='0', value_name='1'))
   c  0  1
0  4  a  1
1  5  a  2
2  6  a  3
3  4  b  9
4  5  b  8
5  6  b  7
```

Another solution with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index('c').stack().reset_index().sort_values('level_1')
df1.columns = ['c', '0','1']
print (df1)
   c  0  1
0  4  a  1
2  5  a  2
4  6  a  3
1  4  b  9
3  5  b  8
5  6  b  7
```

More general solution - use `list comprehension` for filter all columns which are not `a` and `b` to variable `cols`:

```
cols = [col for col in df.columns if col not in ['a','b']]
print (cols)
['c']

print (pd.melt(df,id_vars=cols, var_name='0', value_name='1'))
   c  0  1
0  4  a  1
1  5  a  2
2  6  a  3
3  4  b  9
4  5  b  8
5  6  b  7
```

Sample with added another column `g`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 
                   'b': [9, 8, 7], 
                   'c': [4, 5, 6], 
                   'g': [0, 1, 7]})

print (df)
   a  b  c  g
0  1  9  4  0
1  2  8  5  1
2  3  7  6  7

cols = [col for col in df.columns if col not in ['a','b']]
print (cols)
['c', 'g']
```

Faster solution with [`numpy.setdiff1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html):

```
cols = np.setdiff1d(df.columns, ['a','b']).tolist()
print (cols)
['c', 'g']

print (pd.melt(df,id_vars=cols, var_name='0', value_name='1'))
   c  g  0  1
0  4  0  a  1
1  5  1  a  2
2  6  7  a  3
3  4  0  b  9
4  5  1  b  8
5  6  7  b  7
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks pretty good! However, note that "*the actual data frame has several columns that I would like to keep*" (i.e.: many `c` columns). Is there a way to do it using `a` and `b` as parameters instead of `c`? (`a` and `b` are always 2, but there are a lot of `c` columns with different names, and I would like to keep all of them).

Comment: sure, give me a sec.

Comment: Thanks, a pretty complete answer. I will wait until tomorrow before accepting, in case someone wants to propose a different approach. If, by any chance, I forget to accept it (I don't think so), feel free to "ping" me! :-)

Comment: If my answer was helpful, don't forget accept it. Thanks.